# using jQTouch for large website

Tags: jquery, iphone, jqtouch

- I want to use jQTouch to build iPhone app for large website. When searched for it, I understood that I must edit my HTML code for website to be Suitable to my app, how I can do this without conflict with the style for my website?
- Also, what is the basic steps to using jQTouch ? just Add scripts and Initialize as here : http://code.google.com/p/jqtouch/wiki/GettingStarted .

help me with many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A pretty good idea is to detect the iPhone server-side and then send different HTML with all the jQTouch goodness included and your original style excluded.

Comment: mr.Jakub Hampl, would you please explain more about this? how I can do it ? any simple tutorial for this solution?

Comment: What I mean is that you seem to have a dynamic site. Is it php? So do a check on the User Agent string and if it's an iPhone just render a different file that gives the proper jQTouch html.

Comment: and all two file connect with same DataBase, right? because I want to do the same functions from website and iPhone.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you are extremely lucky, you won't be able to use the same markup for both your normal and jqTouch sites. Your site is likely not a single page application based off of hashed urls.

To get started using jqTouch I'd suggest loading up the demo and editing things in and out of the demo. That will give you the best jump-start into how everything works.

Answer (score 0):

What Jakub suggests is the best answer for you without getting into making an iPhone App. But from experience I also suggest you think about the nature of your application. Basically decide whether your service is something that mentally as soon as the user thinks about it makes them want to open safari.

If not I would suggest you need to consider making a proper app rather than a jQtouch enabled website.

This is mainly because people always prefer the short way to achieve tasks.

And if you have competitors they will just simply make an app after you release and steal your customers.

Comment: As I said before what Jakub is directing you towards is perfectly possible development wise. But that is not what I am trying to point out. From the Human interaction point of view when you want to release an announcement board, probably the neatest way to get maximum users for your app is not to do a jqtouch version of the site. But I think you should make a proper iphone app with the option to alert subscribers of a particular announcement about new posts etc. You can do all this with iPhone App API. However this is just my opinion.