# How make my website like iphone appearence

Tags: iphone

which control should i use to make my company's website to iphone look ...

so that when it open it iphone then it look a different that it look in normal browser...

actually i am an iphone developer and i have to give this answer to the web designer of my group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also a great WordPress plugin called [WPtouch](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptouch/) which I've seen a lot of blogs use. That is, if most of your company's site is a WordPress blog...

Comment: +1--thanks....but if it is not in wordpres then?
and is it my work or web developer's work?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at http://www.jqtouch.com/ or http://code.google.com/p/iui/ or one of the similar toolkits available for doing iPhone web applications.

The actual detection of an iPhone browser depends on your backend framework. A bit more information can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840935)